# Localhost physical path

Tags: php, iis-7, localhost

Right now my localhost path is limited to C:\inetpub\wwwroot. I am using IIS 7.5 and would wish to start working on PHP. before enabling the IIS 7, I was unable to connect to localhost/127.0.0.1. Now, it can connect and display files but I cannot link a workspace to that folder. Is there a way for me to change/edit the physical path for the localhost to source to?

[image]

Thanks,

Legend.

Comment: You might be better posting this on ServerFault.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open up the IIS configuration manager (or something like this, I can't remember the name) in, control panel -> administrative tools.
You can edit/create your local websites there.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to create a different `ISS` webroot all you neeed to do is change the properties of the `default website` as this will simply be `C:\inetpub\wwwroot`.

Keep in mind that the PHP.ini will also need to be amended should you wish to change your webroot.

If however you wish to work on one project, you can create a `website` by right clicking within the right hand menu and choosing new website. The wizard will provide you the ability to customise the settings for one self contained site, one parameter is the root of the website it self e.g `C:\inetpub\wwwroot\mysite1`. You can have many websites using the same site folder.

You will also want to make sure IIS is configured for `.php` files. Take a look at the `FastCGI` module for IIS.

Comment: Thanks for this, I ended up following the other guy's instructions but you did help get it started too :)